# Get the intensity and position of a group of peaks in a image

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I have a photo shown as follow:

[image: Black background with white dots of different intensity]

I want to use Python to identify all the white peaks and tag their position with a series of numbers in that image. And every peak I should return the following info:

- number tag
- position of the peak
- integrated intensity of the peak

I am very new to image processing using python. I have to no idea where to start.

Comment: What packages are you allowed to use? OpenCV? scikit-image? Pillow? NumPy/SciPy?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Your questions should include some research and ideally an attempt at a solution. You can refer here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I indeed should have my initial code first, I looked into OpenCV and scikit-image, and I don't know which one to choose. I am working on the convenient way indeed. Thanks anyway. I think I should at least try.

Comment: Busy with other stuff, sorry for late reply. Thanks for your help:)

Comment: Pleasure! Good luck with your project! Questions (and answers) are free so feel free to come and ask a new question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you want to spend an age getting every last detail in a sophisticated way with some expensive software, or whether you just want to get started with something very simple. Anyway, you could consider using Imagemagick which is free and installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows - with Python, Perl, PHP, .NET, Java, Ruby, C, C++ bindings - [see here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

There is a script from Fred Weinhaus's excellent website called `maxima`, which does much of what you require - it is [here](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/maxima/). It uses and requires Imagemagick.

So, just at the shell in Terminal, you could run the following, assuming your image is named `peaks.gif`:

```
./maxima -r 20 -n 40 peaks.gif result.png
```

**Output**

```
489,0 gray=65535,255,100%
143,99 gray=65535,236,92.549%
144,23 gray=65535,232,90.98%
273,95 gray=65535,232,90.98%
246,168 gray=65535,232,90.98%
118,99 gray=65535,231,90.588%
169,170 gray=65535,231,90.588%
194,100 gray=65535,230,90.196%
91,170 gray=65535,230,90.196%
63,245 gray=65535,230,90.196%
326,168 gray=65535,229,89.804%
352,97 gray=65535,228,89.412%
222,23 gray=65535,227,89.02%
300,96 gray=65535,227,89.02%
142,243 gray=65535,227,89.02%
272,243 gray=65535,227,89.02%
219,247 gray=65535,227,89.02%
274,22 gray=65535,226,88.627%
194,245 gray=65535,226,88.627%
300,23 gray=65535,225,88.235%
221,97 gray=65535,225,88.235%
297,244 gray=65535,225,88.235%
196,23 gray=65535,224,87.843%
194,318 gray=65535,224,87.843%
116,245 gray=65535,223,87.451%
403,170 gray=65535,219,85.882%
115,319 gray=65535,214,83.922%
350,244 gray=65535,208,81.569%
272,319 gray=65535,208,81.569%
378,96 gray=65535,197,77.255%
38,97 gray=65535,196,76.863%
220,319 gray=65535,195,76.471%
298,318 gray=65535,190,74.51%
64,98 gray=65535,189,74.118%
11,171 gray=65535,187,73.333%
117,23 gray=65535,179,70.196%
377,245 gray=65535,177,69.412%
353,22 gray=65535,169,66.275%
142,319 gray=65535,157,61.569%
350,319 gray=65535,144,56.471%
```

[image]

The `-r 20` ignores all peaks within a radius of 20 pixels from any other, the `-n 40` says you want to find 40 peaks. In the output, you can see the coordinates of the peaks and their brightness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scikit-ued. that's what we do in our research.
https://scikit-ued.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/image.html